# Why can I compile successfully without implementing one of the functions?

Tags: c++, oop, class, compilation

I would like to understand how do classes compile in C++.

Why does the code below compile successfully? Doesn't `Foo()` need an implementation for compilation to be successful?

```
class Test{
public:
    Test()  {}
    int Foo();
};

int main()
{
    Test obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "How does a compiler work?" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler

Comment: @Bart, etc.. why did you close it?

Comment: After editing this question it may actually be useful, maybe it should be un-closed?

Answer (score 7):

Nobody tries to call `Foo`, so the linker doesn't complain about the missing implementation, because it's not needed.

If you wrote `virtual int Foo();`, you would see a linker error.

Comment: Why does _**virtual**_ cause the error ? What changes ?

Comment: @EmAdpres: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3560786/14065

Comment: @EmAdpres: you need an entry in the vtable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `Book()` in your code. If you are talking about `Foo()`, you are never using that function within your code, so the linker never gets asked about it and fail with "undefined function" or some similar error.