# What is the underlying mechanism of a base class pointer assigned to derived class

Tags: c++, casting

Similar questions I found were more based on what this does; I understand the assignment of a base class pointer to a derived class, e.g `Base* obj = new Derived()` to be that the right side gets upcasted to a Base* type, but I would like to understand the mechanism for how this happens and how it allows for virtual to access derived class methods. From searching online, someone equated the above code to `Base* obj = new (Base*)Derived`, which is what led to this confusion. If this type-casting is going on at compile-time, why and how can virtual functions access the correct functions (the functions of the Derived class)? Further, if this casting happens in the way I read it, why do we get errors when we assign a non-inheriting class to Base* obj? Thanks, and apologies for the simplicity of the question. I'd like to understand what causes this behavior.

Note: for clarity, in my example, Derived publicly inherits from Base.

Comment: `Base* obj = new (Base*)Derived` is a syntax error . Beware of random online pages about C++, they're mostly the blind leading the blind

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99297/how-are-virtual-functions-and-vtable-implemented

Comment: @M.M thanks for that link - I had perused it, but my question was more to test my understanding of how the declarations work; you said that it's not type-casted as I had believed, and I want to better understand what's going on - the link is great for how VFs are fetched etc. but my question is more when you declare `Base* obj = new Derived()`, what is going on (underlying) in the code?

Comment: The "underlying mechanism" is that each instance of a each class with at least one virtual method has a hidden pointer that specifies what class this object is "really" an instance of, and virtual function calls use it to figure out where virtual method calls end up. This is an oversimplification, and the exact details are entirely up to each C++ implementation. There is no requirement that this is actually how this gets done, but this is the typical approach with most C++ implementation. This hidden pointer is handled entirely by the compiler/library, by themselves.

Answer (score 3):

In a strict sense, the answer to "how does inheritance work at runtime?" is "however the compiler-writer designed it".  I.e., the language specification only describes the behavior to be achieved, not the mechanism to achieve it.

In that light, the following should be seen as analogy.  Compilers will do something analogous to the following:

Given a class `Base`:

```
class Base 
{
    int a;
    int b;
  public:
    Base()
    : a(5),
      b(3)
    { }

    virtual void foo() {}
    virtual void bar() {}
};
```

The compiler will define two structures: one we'll call the "storage layout" -- this defines the relative locations of member variables and other book-keeping info for an object of the class;  the second structure is the "virtual dispatch table" (or vtable).  This is a structure of pointers to the implementations of the virtual methods for the class.

This figure gives an object of type `Base`
[image: An object of type <code>Base</code>, showing member storage and vtable]

Now lets look as the equivalent structure for a derived class, `Derived`:

```
class Derived : public Base 
{
    int c;
  public:
    Derived()
    : Base(),
      c(4)
    { }

    virtual void bar() //Override
    {
      c = a*5 + b*3;
    }
};
```

For an object of type `Derived`, we have a similar structure:
[image: An object of type <code>Derived</code>, with member storage and vtable]

The important observation is that the in-memory representation of both the member-variable storage and the vtable entries, for members `a` and `b`, and methods `foo` and `bar`, are identical between the base class and subclass.  So a pointer of type `Base *` that happens to point to an object of type `Derived` will still implement an access to the variable `a` as a reference to the first storage offset after the vtable pointer.  Likewise, calling `ptr->bar()` passes control to the method in the second slot of the vtable.  If the object is of type `Base`, this is `Base::bar()`; if the object is of type `Derived`, this is `Derived::bar()`.

In this analogy, the `this` pointer points to the member storage block.  Hence, the implementation of `Derived::bar()` can access the member variable `c` by fetching the 3rd storage slot after the vtable pointer, relative to `this`.  Note that this storage slot exists whenever `Derived::bar()` sits in the second vtable slot...i.e., when the object really is of type `Derived`.

---

A brief aside on the debugging insanity that can arise from corrupting the vtable pointer for compilers that use a literal vtable pointer at offset 0 from `this`:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
      std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
  public:
    virtual void bar()
    {
      std::cout << "B::bar()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  A *a = new A();
  B *b = new B();

  std::cout << "A:          ";
  a->foo();
  std::cout << "B:          ";
  b->bar();

  //Frankenobject
  *((void **)a) = *((void **)b); //Overwrite a's vtable ptr with b's.
  std::cout << "Franken-AB: ";
  a->foo();
}
```

Yields:

```
$ ./a.out
A:          A::foo()
B:          B::bar()
Franken-AB: B::bar()
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
```

...note the lack of an inheritance relationship between `A` and `B`... :scream:

Answer (score 0):

Whoever says

```
Base* obj = new Derived();
```

is equivalent to

```
Base* obj = new (Base*)Derived;
```

is ignorant of the subject matter.

It's more like:

```
Derived* temp = new Derived;
Base* obj = temp;
```

The explicit cast is not necessary. The language permits a derived class pointer to be assigned to a base class pointer.

Most of the time the numerical value of the two pointers are same but they are not same when multiple inheritance or virtual inheritance is involved.

It's the compiler's responsibility to make sure that numerical value of the pointer is offset properly when converting a derived class pointer to a base class pointer. The compiler is able to do that since it makes the decision about the layout of the derived class and the base class sub-objects in the derived class object.

> If this type-casting is going on at compile-time, why and how can virtual functions access the correct functions

There is no type casting. There is a type conversion. Regarding the virtual functions, please see [How are virtual functions and vtable implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99297/how-are-virtual-functions-and-vtable-implemented).

> Further, if this casting happens in the way I read it, why do we get errors when we assign a non-inheriting class to `Base*` obj?

This is moot since it does not happen the way you thought they did.