# Unexpected Output...how function binding happens in virtual table

Tags: c++, virtual

```
class Base
{

public:
    int a;
    virtual void fun1()
    {
        cout<<"Hello Base"<<endl;
    }

    void fun2()
    {
       fun1();
    }

};

class Derived: public Base
{
    int a;
    void fun1()
    {
        cout<<"Hello Derived"<<endl;
    }

};


int main()
{
    Base * B = new Derived;
    B->fun2();
    return 1;
}
```

Please help me understand why output is Hello Derived.How this function binding takes place.How is virtual table entry created for Base and derived class.

Comment: If you want `Base::fun2` to call `Base::fun1` then fully qualify it, like I just did in this comment.

Comment: `fun1` is virtual. It doesn't matter where you call it from, it's still virtual.

Comment: Is this what you are asking? [How are virtual functions and vtable implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99297/how-are-virtual-functions-and-vtable-implemented)

Comment: Please understand the basics of the language and search before posting; both the Standardese and compilerese sides of this are amply answered already.

Comment: The C++ standard does not require use of vtables.   It is a common (universal, AFAIK) implementation choice because it offers advantages over alternatives.  The requirement in the standard amounts to, when calling a virtual function through a pointer or reference to `Base`, the function corresponding to the ACTUAL type of the object (in this case `Derived::fun1()`)  is called.   Within `fun2()`, the `this` pointer points at an instance of the most derived type (in this case `Derived`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual table is created when the class objects are constructed. When you construct a `Derived` object, it will first call the `Base` constructor (which creates the vtable and writes its own `Base::fun1` into that. Then the `Derived` constructor runs and overwrites the vtable entry for `fun1` with its own implementation (`Derived::fun1`).

If you then, at any later point (even from within any `Base` function) call `fun1` of such an object instance, it will look into the vtable and call whatever function it finds there. As explained above, it is `Derived::fun1` that is in the vtable of a `Derived` object after construction, so this is the one that will get called. It doesn't matter that you are currently in a `Base` function, the vtable entry does not change.

Note that *during* construction, the vtable is not fully set up: If you were to call `fun1` from within the `Base` constructor, you would *not* call `Derived::fun1` but `Base::fun1` because `Derived` did not replace the vtable entries yet.

Also note that fully specifying the function (e.g. calling `Base::fun1()` on a `Derived` instance) will not do a vtable lookup but instead use exactly the specified function.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
protected:
  void **vt_ptr;
public:

    int a;
    //Executed prior to base member initialization
    //and reexecuted prior to Base destructor call
    void set_dynamic_type(){
      vt_ptr = Base::vtable;
    }

    /*virtual*/
    void fun1(){
       reinterpret_cast<void(*)(Base&)>(vt_ptr[1])(*this);
    }
    void fun2(){
       fun1();
     }

private:
  static void func1_def(Base& pseudo_obj_arg){
        Base* this=&pseudo_obj_arg;
        std::cout<<"Hello Base"<<std::endl;
    }
  static void* vtable[2];
};

void* Base::vtable[2]={
     reinterpret_cast<void*>(&type_id_of_Base),
     reinterpret_cast<void*>(&Base::func1_def)};

class Derived: public Base
{
    int a;
    //Executed after Base intialization, 
    //before Derived member initialization.
    //Reexecuted prior to Derived destructor call
    void set_dynamic_type(){
      Base::vt_ptr = Derived::vtable;
    }


private:
  static void func1_def(Base& pseudo_obj_arg){
      Derived* this=static_cast<Derived*>(&pseudo_obj_arg);
      std::cout<<"Hello Derived"<<std::endl;
  }
  static void* vtable[2];  
};

void* Derived::vtable[2]={
     reinterpret_cast<void*>(&type_id_of_Derived),
     reinterpret_cast<void*>(&Derived::func1_def)};
```

Also a qualified call as in: `obj.Base::func1()`  directly calls `Base::func1_def(obj)`, otherwise it goes throw the devirtualization process described in `Base::func1`.