# Transmogrifying polymorphic object

Tags: c++

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

struct IDivideResult {
    virtual int result() = 0;
    virtual int remainder() = 0;
};

struct DivideResult : IDivideResult {
    DivideResult(int result, int remainder) : result_(result), remainder_(remainder) {}
    int result() override { return result_; }
    int remainder() override { return remainder_; }

    int result_, remainder_;
};

struct LazyDivideResult : IDivideResult {
    LazyDivideResult(int dividend, int divisor) : dividend_(dividend), divisor_(divisor) {}
    int result() override { return Transmogrify()->result(); }
    int remainder() override { return Transmogrify()->remainder(); }

    DivideResult *Transmogrify() {
        int result = dividend_ / divisor_;
        int remainder = dividend_ % divisor_;
        return new (this) DivideResult(result, remainder);
    }

    int dividend_, divisor_;
};

void Print(IDivideResult *div) {
    int result = div->result();
    int remainder = div->remainder();

    std::cout << result << " " << remainder << "\n";
}

int main() {
    IDivideResult *div = new LazyDivideResult(10, 3);
    Print(div);
}
```

The question I have is about behavior of `Print` function.

Expected behavior: after calling `result()` div points to instance of `DivideResult` class, calling  `remainder()` function calls `DivideResult::remainder()` function.

Possible (?) behavior: at the moment of calling `result()` pointer to `vtable` 
of `LazyDivideResult` is cached. The next call to `remainder()` reuses previously cached pointer to `vtable` and hence calls `LazyDivideResult::remainder()`.

I've heard that virtual tables are not part of C++ standard. Also disassembly of clang/gcc/msvc generated code renders expected behavior.

So question here is: is compiler allowed to generate code that leads to "possible behavior" described above? Are there any guarantees?

Comment: C++ compilers are not required to use vtables to implement polymorphism. It just turns out that almost all of them do. But if the compiler can see an optimisation that can eliminate them, and still lead to correct behaviour, it's allowed to do it. This might help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99297/how-are-virtual-functions-and-vtable-implemented

Comment: Are you interested in knowing how to do this _without_ UB, or only in confirming that this specific code is indeed awful and wrong?

Comment: I'm aware of methods how to implement this without this "substitution" trick. I'm asking here about compilers behavior. And it seems that the answer is "behavior is undefined, refer to compiler documentation/code".

Comment: Also I've seen these kind of tricks in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) examples for `std::launder` function. So maybe it is not that much "undefined"?

Comment: You'd need to launder the pointer _outside_ the function to get the guarantee you're hoping for.

Comment: What you mean? Should I call `Print(launder(div))`? But it does not make sense, since `div` points to different instance only after calling `result()` function. Or should I call `remainder()` function like this: `launder(div)->remainder()`. Also deletion of object (in `main` function) must be performed this way: `delete launder(div)`? Will any of that remove undefined behavior?

Comment: @purecuteness You have a number of `IDivideResult *` (or derived) pointers. In `main` you have `div`, in `Print` you have `div` and in `result` and `remainder` you have `this`. Each has to be properly laundered, after each `Transmogrify`, before it can be used again.

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behaviour.

Once you call `div->result()`, the pointer `div` becomes invalid, because you have ended the lifetime of the object it points to. The symptom you observe is that it "succeeds" in calling a `remainder`.

In theory, an implementation could assume that you only ever pass `DivideResult` to `Print`, because passing a `LazyDivideResult` would be UB.

Comment: What about `std::launder` from c++17? Will `std::launder(div)->remainder()` make the behavior defined?

Comment: You'd also need to propagate the laundering back to `main` so you can `delete` safely

Comment: And for further avoidance of UB, you'd better `static_assert(sizeof(DivideResult) <= sizeof(LazyDivideResult))` somewhere

Comment: It should be `<=`, because `DivideResult` must fit space which was occupied by `LazyDivideResult`.