# Code structure for different versions of devices

Tags: c++, architecture, version, driver

I am writing a "device driver" (C++14) which can handle multiple versions of protocols meant for different versions of devices. This device driver is running on an external PC which communicates with the device over Ethernet with a HTTP based protocol. There are common functionalities for all versions, but some functions maybe additional in certain versions of the protocol.

Below is an example:

```
class ProtocolBase {
public:
    virtual void reset_parameters() {
        std::cout << "reset parameters" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void set_parameters() {
        std::cout << "set parameters" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ProtocolV1 : public ProtocolBase
{
public:
    void set_parameters() override {
        std::cout << "set parameters for V1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ProtocolV2 : public ProtocolBase 
{
public:
    void set_parameters() override {
        std::cout << "set parameters for V2" << std::endl;
    }

    void reset_parameters() {
        std::cout << "reset parameters for V2" << std::endl;
    }

    void do_V2() {
        std::cout << "doing V2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Below is the `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int version = std::atoi(argv[1]);

    std::unique_ptr<ProtocolBase> protocol = std::make_unique<ProtocolV1>();
    switch (version)
    {
    case 1:
        /* do nothing at the moment */
        break;
    case 2:
        protocol.reset(new ProtocolV2);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    protocol->reset_parameters();

    if(ProtocolV2* p = dynamic_cast<ProtocolV2*>(protocol.get())) { //not sure about this
        p->do_V2();
    }else {
        std::cout << "This functionality is unavailable for this device" << std::endl;
    }
    protocol->set_parameters();
    return 0;
}
```

I have a feeling using `dynamic_cast` is not the best way to go here. Looking forward to some feedback.

**Edit:** As per @Ptaq666's answer, I modified `ProtocolBase` and `ProtocolV2` as:

```
class ProtocolBase {
public:
    virtual void do_V(){
        std::cerr << "This functionality is unavailable for this device" << std::endl;
    }
};
class ProtocolV2 : public ProtocolBase 
{
public:
    void do_V() override {
        std::cout << "doing V2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

With this, there's no need for `dynamic_cast` anymore, though base class will have to know all the functionalities. This seems to be the best solution for now.

Comment: The good example is here: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/public/platform/web_input_event.h The input event type (protocol version in your case) is asigned in the input event constructs. The input event type is determined by methods like `IsMouseEventType` that will be `IsProtocolV2` in your case

Comment: Also what is ```Protocol```  in the second line of the main ```std::unique_ptr<Protocol> protocol = std::make_unique<ProtocolV1>();``` Did you meant ```ProtocolBase```?

Comment: Ah my bad, yes I meant `ProtocolBase`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I can't see any problem with it if the functions are not dependent on any data members which might differ in derived classes! What is it you are not exactly sure of? what are your concerns?

Comment: @Fareanor you were right but even that did not matter in this specific case!

Comment: @harsh is there going to be a data member or not?

Comment: The `dynamic_cast` I am doing will be actually inside a callback function which will be called from a client. So for each functionality I will have to `dynamic_cast` to see if that functionality exists for the current protocol. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of handling this.

Comment: Dear @harsh with these type of member functions which don't depend on anything, believe me there will be no problem my friend! Please take a look at my answer! Just try it to see it does not matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in most cases when it comes to chose the appropriate system architecture the answer is
"it depends" :). The most comfortable solution would be to introduce protocol-specific behavior
of the `ProtocolBase` subclasses in their constructors

```
class ProtocolV2 : public ProtocolBase 
{
public:
    ProtocolV2::ProtocolV2(args) {
        // set some params that will determine when do_V2() is called
        // it can be some numeric setting, a callback, or similar
    }
    void set_parameters() override {
        // you can use V2 behavior here maybe?
        std::cout << "set parameters for V2" << std::endl;
    }

    void reset_parameters() override {
        // or here maybe?
        std::cout << "reset parameters for V2" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    void do_V2() {
        std::cout << "doing V2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

If for some reason you cannot do this, there is a possibility to keep `do_V2()` as public
non-virtual method, but to call it before passing `ProtocolV2` as a pointer to `ProtocolBase`
to the sysytem that will use it. Of course the limitation is that `do_V2` can only be called outside
your system scope, which might not really solve the problem.

Another option is to actually move `do_V2()` to the interface:

```
class ProtocolBase {
public:
    virtual void reset_parameters() {
        std::cout << "reset parameters" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void set_parameters() {
        std::cout << "set parameters" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void do_V2() {
        std::cout << "not supported" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and implement it as "not supported" behavior by default. Only `ProtocolV2` will implement this behavior
as a valid part of the protocol.

In the end, if none of the above is OK, you can of course use the dynamic_cast as you proposed.
Personally I try to avoid `dynamic_cast` because my office mates will start to abuse it for sure,
but in some cases it is a correct solution.

Also if you decide to cast the pointer, use `std::shared_ptr` with `dynamic_pointer_cast` instead of accessing a raw pointer from `unique_ptr`.

Comment: I think I would prefer to use your second option, moving the function to interface. Reason being, I might have more than 2 variations of the protocol. I will have to keep track of which function is implemented in which protocol. The easiest would be to have an "empty" virtual function in the base, and the respective derived class would implement it.

Answer (score 0):

In general it depends on how the derived classes `ProtocolV1` and `ProtocolV2` are formed and what are the data members and weather if the respective member functions are going to use different data members or not!

The reason is simply since there is no dependency to member data, the member functions are only sensitive to the **type** of the objects that they have been called with, not their **value/state**!

It is like having a (non member) function overload like:

```
void function(ProtocolV1 *){
        std::cout << "set parameters for V1" << std::endl;
}
void function(ProtocolV2 *){
        std::cout << "set parameters for V2" << std::endl;
}
```

And then calling it once by a pointer of type `ProtocolV1 *` and once with  null pointer of type`ProtocolV2 *`.

If you like alternatives for the usage you presented in the question you can even use C-style cast:
The result was the ***SAME***!

Finally if you are going to call the member function to then call another function from it which requires some data member/s ,which is/are **different** across the derived classes as its argument/s, then you can not use any cast unless you introduce some form of compensation to fill the data that is not presented in the casted type!

Good luck!

Comment: @harsh if this helped please consider voting/accepting it!

Comment: Fareanor remark about `ProtocolV2* p` lifetime is not really on topic and there is no problem with memory management. Your example with `nullptr` cast and `nullptr` dereference is also wrong. Dereferencing null pointer is Undefined Behavior ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) ). Finally, question is about how to design  a system properly (with dynamic cast or some other approach), not how to cast a pointer.

Comment: @Ptaq666 interestingly enough I was just about to ask similar thing as question as I was getting to doubt that my self! Thank you!

Comment: But I am a little bit confused were you dressing me or @Fareanor or me or both?

Comment: @Ptaq666 now that I am thinking about it I am seriously in doubt! is it OK with you that I post it a s question?

Comment: @Ptaq666 I deleted my answer so. But I think you are wrong. `ProtocolBase` has no virtual destructor, so, when deleting `protocol`, the derived destructor will never be called -> possible memory leak if the derived class has manually-allocated members. (But you are right, it was not the question, this is why I deleted my answer).

Comment: Sure you can post a question :) [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/461224/4165552) explains very well why DTor should be virtual in this case (not only because of memleak). In case of virtual methods, comparison to free functions accepting `this` as an argument is not entirely correct, because of vtable (how most compilers implement virtual methods). Take look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99297/how-are-virtual-functions-and-vtable-implemented).