# C++ Virtual Pointer and its mechanism

Tags: c++, vtable

I am positing this because after reading many posts and answers I still didn't get my answer.
Please kindly flag this as duplicate if it is so.

I understand that in C++, the virtual function is implemented through virtual pointer and virtual table.

However I am not sure how does C++ compiler decipher which virtual pointer to use in runtime?

In below simple case:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual foo() {}
}

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    foo() override {}
}

int main() {
  D* p_derived = new Derived();
  B* p_base = p_derived;

  p_derived->foo();
  p_base->foo();
}
```

I understand that `p_derived->foo()` will look for `Derived::vptr` per se for the `Derived::vtable` (namingly) then `Derived::foo()`, and `p_base->foo()` follows the same path as `Derived::vptr -> Derived::vtable -> Derived::foo()`. But how does `p_base->foo()` finds `Derived::vptr`
 even though it's static type is `Base*`? What prevents `p_base` from finding `Base::vptr` instead?

Many Thanks

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What is `d`?

Comment: Have you seen this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99297/how-are-virtual-functions-and-vtable-implemented)?

Comment: With nice pictures [Understandig Virtual Tables in C++](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2017/06/10/understanding-virtual-tables/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, I've corrected it. I have read the above reference pages word by word. But they don't contain the answer of how p_base find Derived::vptr by looking at the static type Base*

Comment: I wrote a brief overview for [Undefined reference to vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable/57504289#57504289) -- is that the sort of thing you are looking for? (I intentionally skimped on some details since they are not the focus of that question.)

Comment: @JaMiT thank you, your post definitely helps. I think I got it now. I was under impression that a derived class contains two virtual points, 1 from its parent 1 from its own. Everything makes sense now if derived class only contains 1 virtual pointer and 1 virtual table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really think that related answer has all you need to know, but there might be a bit missing.

The vtable is implementation defined, so anything that works is OK according to the standards.

One way to do it is to have the actual vtable be const static, and in each constructor the single pointer is updated to point to each new class vtable. This has double indirection penalty, but one benefit is it is impossible for malware to overwrite the function pointer.

Another method is to have a table, aka array, of pointers. Virtual pointer table: vtable. In this method each set of pointers is set during each constructor. Or at least it appears that way: optimizers can do strange things.

Things can get extremely complicated with multiple inheritance, multiple virtual inheritance, etc. There could even be nested vtables: tables pointing to other tables!

Then of course we get whole program optimization. LTO on Unixes. LTCG in MSVC, etc. The optimizer can go through the program and if it can determine that the virtual call can only go to one target function, then it replaces the call with a non-virtual direct call. Then reruns the inlining pass. Profile directed optimization can even take a variable virtual function and determine it is calling class A 80% of the time. Then it might always call A, with an out-of-line check to see if it was actually B or something else.

But in the simple case you laid out, class Base has a vtable with one function pointer to foo. When the Base() constructor runs it is set to Base::foo. After Derived() runs it is set to Derived::foo()

Without complex virtual inheritance or multiple inheritance, the base (Base in your case) class is always at the front of the structure. So a pointer to Base always points to the front. Where the vtable is. Pointers to Derived also point to the front. Both classes use the same vtable and call whichever function is set there.

Comment: uhh! so class Derived only contains 1 virtual table, not 2? I thought class Derived contains 2 virtual pointers and 2 virtual tablets because it inherits from class Base. That's probably where I got confused. Thanks for helping me make this clear.

Comment: Base is not required to be at front by standard. Even if no virtual table involved at all, except for case when base class is the only one class which contains objects declared  non-static members variables (i.e. a pointer to it can be equal to the pointer to containing object, as it is being the only, therefore the first).

Answer (score 0):

p_base is only a pointer instead of an instance. I think the vptr that p_base can access is the vptr of p_derived.

Comment: You can leave a comment on such an answer, not in the actual thread!