# How does C++ know which element in vector<Base*> is Derived*?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, derived-class

How does C++/the compiler know in the code below when to execute the right piece of code? And how is this stored (behind the scenes)? My vector contains `Base*` but there must be some extra information somewhere, right?

The [compiling code](https://repl.it/@DennisJM/DeepPeachpuffComments#main.cpp) which is the same as this:

```
class Base {
    public:
        Base()=default;   
        virtual void DerivedOrBase() { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        Derived()=default;   
        void DerivedOrBase() override { std::cout << "Derived\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*> myVector;
    myVector.push_back(new Base());
    myVector.push_back(new Base());
    myVector.push_back(new Base());
    myVector.push_back(new Derived());
    
    for(auto p : myVector) p->DerivedOrBase();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's all about how polymorphism works in general. Nothing special for `std::vector` of other standard containers.

Comment: Are you asking this essentially? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99297/how-are-virtual-functions-and-vtable-implemented

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes! That could be an answer to my question, the v-table!